# Html.ActionLink: popup(custom), then redirect

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to show popup when person clicks on button(which is already done with `Html.ActionLink` - older code; popup only shows if session variable equals some value...this part is alredy figured out) and is then redirected or new view is returned(this is done in controller).

I have `Html.ActionLink(<button name>, <controller>, <action>)` and out of that with help of other answers here I made `Html.ActionLink(<button name>, <controller>, <action>, null, new { onlick: 'myPopup();'})` where `myPopup()` is function that creates [qjuery modal popup](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

But my issue is that sometimes popup doesn't even show or only for few seconds. I think that it's because javascript is async and controller is faster so it returns before javascript code is executed. Does anyone know how to execute javascript code first and then controller code.

I tried to `Html.ActionLink(<button name>, <controller>, <action>, null, new { onlick: 'myPopup();return false;'})` as `return false` should stop default behavior(redirecting to Controller/Action) and then in jquery code I put ajax redirect to controller when button `OK` in popup is clicked. But problem is I can't seem to make this work, it may be even wrong way?

Any suggestions how to add this function?

Answer (score 1):

Hi and welcome to SO :)

You would need to handle the redirect within your myPopup() function. Assuming you have a "continue" button within your modal. One way you could do it is -

```
$('#actionLinkId').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#continue').attr('href', link);

    $('#yourModalId').modal();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I just have two questions. 1. How do you think `Html.ActionLink` parameters should look like? 2. What is meant for class `className`...is it class for div for popup?

Comment: OK slight edit (no need for class name)... add an ID to your ActionLink (new { id = "actionLinkId" }) and add the same id to the jQuery above (replacing '#actionLinkId') hopefully that puts you in the right direction